# Find matching rows associated with the ref passed in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to pass a reference number in a stored procedure which will give me all the other reference number which has matching name and address in the passed in reference number.

Eg.  If I pass in 27 in the table below

```
RefNo         Name                Address
47            ABC                 CBA
27            ZYX                 XYZ
46            LKJ                 JKL
745           ZYX                 XYZ
3456          LKJ                 JKL
364           ZYX                 XYZ
```

I want the stored procedure to return 27, 745 and 364.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c39a4/5

```
create procedure proc1   
 @ref int
as

select a.refno from table1 a
inner join table1 b
  on a.name=b.name and a.address = b.address
where b.refno=@ref
```